# Why build of mono failed

Tags: mono

I built mono 5.20.1.19 from tarball successfully. But the build of master from github was failed. Instead of using a existing mono installation for the build, I run make get-monolite-latest for the mcs. On RedHat 6.9 (gcc6.3, cmake3.7.2) the build was crashed(segment fault). On SUSE 12.4(gcc6.3, cmake 3.5.2), the build ended with errors. I thought I might need to checkout the branch 5.20.1.19, but I couldn't find any branch newer then 4.8. Why there doesn't exist such a branch? Thanks in advance. Below are my build errors:

RedHat 6.9

make -C build-shared
make[4]: Entering directory `mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[5]: Entering directory`mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[6]: Entering directory `mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
Scanning dependencies of target pqueue
make[6]: Leaving directory`mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[6]: Entering directory `mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
[  1%] Building C object boringssl/ssl/pqueue/CMakeFiles/pqueue.dir/pqueue.c.o
^[l/bin/sh: line 1: 42877 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /opt/anss/bin/ccache /opt/anss/bin/gcc -DBORINGSSL_IMPLEMENTATION -Imono-src/external/boringssl/ssl/../include -Imono-src/external/boringssl/ssl/pqueue/../../include -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wmissing-field-initializers -fPIC -ggdb -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -Wformat=2 -Wsign-compare -Wmissing-field-initializers -ggdb -fvisibility=hidden -Wshadow -std=c11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -o CMakeFiles/pqueue.dir/pqueue.c.o -c mono-src/external/boringssl/ssl/pqueue/pqueue.c
make[6]: *** [boringssl/ssl/pqueue/CMakeFiles/pqueue.dir/pqueue.c.o] Error 139
make[6]: Leaving directory`mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[5]: *** [boringssl/ssl/pqueue/CMakeFiles/pqueue.dir/all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory`mono-src/mono/btls/build-shared'
make[3]:**  [build-shared/libmono-btls-shared.so] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `mono-src/mono/btls'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`mono-src/mono'
make[1]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `mono-src'
make: *** [all] Error 2

SUSE12.4
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
Directory does not exist: 'mono-src/external/nuget-buildtasks/src/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
// gensources produced 8 error(s) and a set of 155 filename(s)
// Invoked with 'mono-src/mcs/class/lib/build/gensources.exe --strict --platformsdir:./../../build ../../build/deps/_xbuild_14__Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll.sources Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll  xbuild_14'
// Working directory was 'mono-src/mcs/class/Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks'
make[8]: *** No rule to make target '../../build/deps/_xbuild_14__Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll.sources', needed by '../../build/deps/_xbuild_14__Microsoft.NuGet.Build.Tasks.dll.response'.  Stop.
../../build/rules.make:226: recipe for target 'do-all' failed
make[7]: *** [do-all] Error 2

Comment: Master is not guaranteed to build all the times. Use a release branch is recommended.

Comment: git branch -a shows lots of branches. But I didn't see a branch named mono-5.x or release. When you say using a release branch, did you mean using a tarball?

Comment: New release branches are named `2019-xx`.

Comment: Tried to build 2019-04. The build on SUSE12.4 was successful, unfortunately on RH6.9 it was still failed with the same error. Seems it's related to boringssl/ssl/pqueue, but how a build triggered segmentation error. Who triggered, ccache or gcc?

Comment: why build it yourself when you can consume the packages provided for RedHat?

Comment: It's not necessary, if the mono is used by myself but if  the mono is part of products shipped to customers it's a different story. A software product definites the versions of is it supports. In case of Linux, the mono must be build on the lowest version of Linux that the product supports. Otherwise you may see the dependent system libraries not found problem on a older version of the Linux where the product is deployed. A prebuild mono doesn't meet this criteria. Not to say we need to customerize a little bit for our product.